# text-align: center not working in my nav

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav, text-align

I am trying to center my navigation. The CSS text-align: center; is not working. It doesn't seem to affect the nav in anyway, shape, or form.

here's my html:

```
<nav id="user_nav"><ul>
       <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Followers</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Interests</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

here's my CSS:

```
#user_nav {
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

#user_nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#user_nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}

#user_nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px 25px 0 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: left;
}
```

Please note: I am trying to make the links centered horizontally as well as vertically.

If there is a better way to do it than how I am doing it now, I am open to suggestions.

Please help me.

Comment: You can't use `text-align` alongside `float`: `float` will stop it from being an element of type `display: inline;`, and `text-align` requires the element to be either `inline` or `inline-block`.

Comment: @setek for some reason when I don't add float: left; CSS won't let me horizontally center it. If you know a better way, please answer the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KCm87/4/)

**CSS**

```
 #user_nav {
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

#user_nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#user_nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;    
}

#user_nav ul li a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 15px 25px 0 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="user_nav"><ul>
       <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Followers</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Interests</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `display: table-cell;` on the `a`: you can just have it as `block`. It's constrained by the parent `inline-block`.

Comment: +1 Other than my previous comment, this is good. You might want to take the time to explain why OP's code wasn't working, and why yours will.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AyOXATA/1/edit)**

```
#user_nav {
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

#user_nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#user_nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

If you use `inline-block` you'll need to space the elements out manually by setting the width: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/AyOXATA/3/edit)**

```
#user_nav {
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

#user_nav ul {
  width: 100%;
}

#user_nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```